# Lenovo P1/X1Extreme "official" support?

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad

Lenovo claims that they have received Canonical's Ubuntu certification (whatever that means) for the P1 and the X1 Extreme Thinkpads.

Is there some secret location to get the right installation media from? Linux was not listed as an option when I bought the device last month, and it was only later that I found about this official support. I don't mind paying for them, it will be noise compared to what the laptop cost!

I had a terrible time installing 18.04LTS on my new P1 (the solution was to first install 16.04 and then upgrade; found this on someone's web page). Some things are still not working right, and I really don't want to run Windows!

Comment: I actually have the same problem. https://certification.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201809-26479/ claimes it need to be pre installed and https://www.lenovo.com/linux just links back to the first link. It however also mentions to be RHEL Certified (with no string attached?) https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Extreme shows some problems with fan noise. so what should we do?

Comment: PS We might try PopOS first (ubuntu based) which comes with a 3rd party nvidia driver.

Comment: The bigger problem, and one for which Canonical should NEVER have granted them certification, is that there is no driver for the fingerprint reader. It's not even documented that there is no support, you only find out about it by wading through the Lenovo fora.

Comment: I am quite happy using PopOs. For me the fingerprint reader is something i do not want anyways and i would have disabled it anyway.

Comment: Irrelevant on two counts. This is about Ubuntu, not PopOs. Also, Canonical certified a device that is not fully compatible with Ubuntu. Whether you, or anyone else, needs that functionality has nothing to do with it.